# Convert day of week name to day of week number Vertica

Tags: sql, database, vertica

- With this way - `SELECT TO_CHAR(NOW(), 'DAY');` I can get a day of week name(E.G. MONDAY).
- With `SELECT dayofweek(NOW());` I can get the number of the day of week. (E.G 1)
- **QUESTION:**
  How to convert day of week name to day of week number. (E.G  MONDAY -> 1)
  SMTH like `TO_NUMBER('MONDAY', 'DAY'); --> 1` (just for example, don't working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a `case` expression is the simplest method:

```
(case ? 
    when 'MONDAY' then 1
    when 'TUESDAY' then 2
    when 'WEDNESDAY' then 3
    when 'THURSDAY' then 4
    when 'FRIDAY' then 5
    when 'SATDAY' then 6
    when 'SUNDAY' then 7
 end)
```

Or arrays are more concise:

```
array_find(?,
           array['MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY']
          ) + 1
```

Comment: and how to use it correctly?
F.E. 
* SELECT * FROM table t where DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) BETWEEN t.startDay AND t.endDay array_find(?,
           array['MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY']
          ) + 1

Comment: The `?` is for whatever expression or parameter defines the day of the week.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table dp where dp.end_day = array_find(array['MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY'], TO_CHAR(NOW(), 'DAY'));`
but getting `[Vertica][VJDBC](3457) ERROR: Function array_find(varchar[], varchar) does not exist, or permission is denied for array_find(varchar[], varchar)`

Comment: https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.3.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Array/ARRAY_FIND.htm.